# Gravity Forms - Populate ACF Relation field with Gravity checkbox

Tags: arrays, wordpress, forms, advanced-custom-fields, gravity

I am using Gravity with ACF for post fields and the addon ["Advanced post creation"](https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/advanced-post-creation/) in order to create a Post when users populate their form.
On theses posts, there is an ACF relationship field I would like to populate.

My request is :
I would like to know how to populate the [ACF Relationship field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) with a Gravity Checkbox into my form listing many Posts title ?

Here's my current code with some comments.
I am using [Gravity hook](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_advancedpostcreation_post_after_creation/) with [ACF function](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) to update the concerning relation field.

```
// 6 is the form id 

add_action( 'gform_advancedpostcreation_post_after_creation_6', 'apc_serialize_checkboxes', 10, 4 );

function gform_relation( $post_id, $feed, $entry, $form ) {


// Checkboxes field id.

$field_id = 21;

// Get field object.

$field = GFAPI::get_field( $form, $field_id );

if ( $field->type == 'checkbox' ) {
    
    $checked = $field->get_value_export( $entry );

// The form entries look like this : Post title 1, Post title 2...

// As I only get "Post title" as values, I convert the "Post title" into ID 
//in order to build an array for my ACF relation field.

    foreach ($checked as $check) {
        $my_post = get_page_by_title( $check, OBJECT, 'post' );
        echo $my_post->ID;
    }

    // Convert to array

    $values = explode( ', ', $checked );

}

// 'parcours_thematiques_choisies' is the ACF relation field key. 
// The return format is "Post Id".

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'parcours_thematiques_choisies', $values );
}
```

Thanks for your back !

Answer (score 0):

Good evening Fxmly92, as you mentioned above, to use GRAVITY with ACF in checkbox fields it is necessary to use a code to convert the data, as GRAVITY stores data in one way and ACF in another.

to use just one checkbox field, use the following code in your theme's functions.php:

```
//  CONVERT CHECKBOX FROM GRAVITY TO ACF
add_action( 'gform_advancedpostcreation_post_after_creation_1', 'apc_serialize_checkboxes', 10, 4 );
function apc_serialize_checkboxes( $post_id, $feed, $entry, $form ) {

    // Checkboxes field id.
    $field_id = YOUR GRAVITY FIELD ID;

    // Get field object.
    $field = GFAPI::get_field( $form, $field_id );

    if ( $field->type == 'checkbox' ) {
        // Get a comma separated list of checkboxes checked
        $checked = $field->get_value_export( $entry );

        // Convert to array.
        $values = explode( ', ', $checked );

    }

    // Replace my_custom_field_key with your custom field meta key.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'YOUR ACF META KEY', $values );
}
```

Replace the YOUR GRAVITY FIELD ID field with the ID of the checkbox in the form, for example 4.

Replace YOUR ACF META KEY with the ACF meta key, for example cars_brand.

If you have more than one checkbox you can use the following structure:

```
add_action( 'gform_advancedpostcreation_post_after_creation_1', 'apc_serialize_checkboxes', 10, 4 );
function apc_serialize_checkboxes( $post_id, $feed, $entry, $form ) {

    // Checkboxes field ids.
    $field_id_1 = YOUR GRAVITY FIELD ID;
    $field_id_2 = YOUR GRAVITY FIELD ID;

    // Get field objects.
    $field_1 = GFAPI::get_field( $form, $field_id_1 );
    $field_2 = GFAPI::get_field( $form, $field_id_2 );

    $values_1 = array();
    $values_2 = array();

    // Check if the first field is a checkbox.
    if ( $field_1->type == 'checkbox' ) {
    $checked_1 = $field_1->get_value_export( $entry );
    $values_1 = explode( ', ', $checked_1 );
    }

    // Check if the second field is a checkbox.
    if ( $field_2->type == 'checkbox' ) {
        $checked_2 = $field_2->get_value_export( $entry );
        $values_2 = explode( ', ', $checked_2 );
    }

    // Remove any duplicates and empty values.
    $values_1 = array_filter( array_unique( $values_1 ) );
    $values_2 = array_filter( array_unique( $values_2 ) );

    // Replace 'setores_tecnologicos' and 'outra_meta_key' with your actual meta keys.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'YOUR ACF META KEY', $values_1 );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'YOUR ACF META KEY', $values_2 );
}
```

If necessary add other options just follow the structure.

A tip for you to answer questions of this type is to use OPEN AI's CHAT GPT, you can use the free CHAT GPT 3.5, it will be enough to answer you.

I apologize for my English, I'm Brazilian and I'm not fluent in your language, but I hope I helped with your question, I'm available for any new questions that may arise. Good luck with your project!